# What applications can I film in and integrate photos, and narrating on iMac/iPhone/Maybe iPad 

Tags: video, editing, producing, diy, imovie

What applications can I film in and integrate photos, and narrating?

I've played with iMovie and don't get it (ADHD), and video apps on my iPhone seem puny for a series of youTube like documentary chapters. There is the iMac remote control, and I have Apple TV for Screening.

I know this sounds obvious but I want the final cut to be a little slick, as a tool to sell the idea of not quitting after 21 years, or to use in the slightly landmark divorce, (hope not).

Comment: Sorry, but I find it really hard to understand what is being asked here. Could I persuade you to tidy up/simplify your question a little bit? Make it more focused. Exactly what do you want an answer to?

Comment: I edited the question quite heavily to make it more universal.

Answer (score 1):

iMovie is extremely easy to use - maybe you just need to find some local classes or a friend who can walk you through the process?

Alternately, try writing up the screenplay version of your story so you can shop it around to local producers. If you can write out a compelling story, you will have an easier to finding people to collaborate with you. And the written document may help you structure your recording and editing process.

Answer (score 0):

I would still stick with iMovie - as it's probably going to be the easiest you'll find.

The process I would take is to first record the audio in a separate program. Audacity, QuickTime, whatever - just record it in a high quality format (16-bit, 48000hz, uncompressed, mono, AIFF/WAV, ideally. Record the audio in this app, whilst flicking through the photos in Preview or however else you view photos.

Once you've got the audio recorded, add it into a new iMovie project (should just be able to drag the audio file from the Finder into the iMovie timeline), then play through the iMovie project with your audio, pausing to add in the photos as per your narration, that you're now listening to. If your photos are in iPhoto, you can just use the media browser in iMovie to add in the photos directly from iPhoto.

At the end of that, you'll have a timeline in iMovie full of still photos, as well as your audio track. You can then add any transitions or effects (I probably wouldn't bother, but you may want to do the Ken Burns effect on your photos to get that zooming in/out effect, like, err, a Ken Burns documentary :p). iMovie has an export to YouTube function, so just use that to upload to YouTube. You can also export a higher quality version suitable for the Apple TV as well.